# Let D be a nonempty set. Suppose f : D -> R and g : D - >R are bounded functions

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

a) show that inf(f(x) + g(x)) $\geq$ inf f(x) + inf g(x)

b) Find examples where we obtain strict inequality.

I already proved a), but I have no idea how to find an example for a)..

Comment: Try using $D = \{0, 1\}$.

Answer (score 1):

Try to find examples where $f(x)$ takes certain low values, and $g(x)$ also takes certain low values, but they never both do it for the same value of $x$.

Comment: I could find $f(x) = (-1) ^n$ and $g(x) = (-1)^{n+1}$, but I used this example for sup f + g $\leq$ sup f + sup g....  hum. need to find another one..

Comment: If you mean $f(n)$, then yes, that would work. It works for both.